# Functional Poincaré Lemma for second-order PDE $\Delta u(x) + F(\nabla u(x))=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Suppose I can write a second-order elliptic PDE for an unknown function $u:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ in the form $$\Delta u(x) + F(\nabla u(x))=0\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb R^n.$$ **Under what conditions on the (potentially nonlinear) function $F:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ does this PDE correspond to the Euler-Lagrange equation of some functional acting on $u$?**

For example, if $F(v)\equiv0$ then the resulting PDE $\Delta u=0$ (Laplace's Equation) is the Euler-Lagrange equation corresponding to the Dirichlet energy $u\mapsto \int \|\nabla u(x)\|_2^2\,d\mathrm{Vol}(x)$.

*More generically, I'm looking for a functional version of [Poincaré's Lemma](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoincaresLemma.html) relevant to second-order PDE.  Posts like [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429276/functional-poincar%C3%A9s-lemma-and-the-inverse-lagrangian-problem) and [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20298/how-do-i-show-that-there-exists-variational-action-principle-for-a-given-classic) are relevant, but I had trouble translating them into the case I'm interested in.*

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0207039.pdf Theorem 1.2 and equation (1.6) probably explain the things you want.

Comment: definitely looks relevant!  i just need to remember how to read this complicated notation :-)

Comment: could you share a little context about this abstraction? It might simplify the search for a solution.